# Implementación del operador 'in' en Java

Tags: java

Quería implementar la siguiente función de Python en Java. Tengo una serie de dudas un poco más simples y son las siguientes:

1. Quería saber si con `a:b` estamos implementado el operador in de otros lenguajes como Python
2. Quería saber si es lo mismo `count += 1` que `count ++`

   ```
   def sentences(param):`

       vocales = "AEIOUÁÉÍÓÚÜaeiouáéíóúü"
       contador = 0

       if len(param) > 0:
           for i in param.split():
               if i[0] in vocales:
                   contador += 1

       return contador
   ```

**Código en Java**

```
public class Inicio {

    public static int vocales(String param) {

        String comprobacion = "AEIOUÁÉÍÓÚÜaeiouáéíóúü";
        int count = 0;
        String [] sentence = param.split(" ");

        if (param.length() > 0) {
            for (String i:sentence) {         
                if (i.charAt(0):comprobacion) {    // Se produce el error
                    count += 1;                   
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Comment: y en la linea del if lo que quieres es ver si cada palabra separada por espacio" " contiene una o más vocales de las que tienes guardas en tu string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

te explico un poco como funciona esto en Java.

La primera sentencia que mencionas es un foreach, esta compuesto de tres partes la primera es el tipo de dato de la variable, la segunda el nombre de la variable y la tercera despues de los dos puntos es la lista de la que se extraeran los elementos, esto serve para interar los elementos de la lista que seran asignados a la variable en cada iteración, entonces en tu caso `String words:sentence` iteraras los elementos del array `sentence` y en cada iteración este elemento sera asignado a la variable `words`.

La segunda sentencia, por lo explicado anteriormente la sentencia `words.charAt(0):vowels` no funcionara en un if ya que no retorna un valor boleano y en relidad tampoco en un foreach por lo explicado anteriormente, entiendo que en Python evaluas si el primer caracter esta contenido en la cadena en java lo puedes realizar de varias formas una de ellas es `String.contains(Character.toString(words.charAt(0)))`.

La tercera sentencia `count+=1` es igual a `count = count + 1` y count++ incrementa el valor de count pero devolvera el valor original de count antes del incremento, en tu caso funcionara y no notaras la diferencia pero te dejo un ejemplo para que lo entiendas de mejor manera:

i = 1;
 j = ++i;
 (i es 2, j es 2)

i = 1;
 j = i++;
 (i es 2, j es 1)

La respuesta esta en base a la primera versión de tu pregunta. Espero te sirva.

Comment: Hola, foreach es el termino adecuado según la documentación. Por favor no confundir con forEach de los Stream en la progrmación funcional que se incorporo en Java 8.

Comment: Gracias por la explicación. La sentencia String.contains(Character.toString(words.charAt(0))), ¿se puede emplear dentro de un if?. He tratado de implementar la instrucción  if i[0] in vocales de Python pero no la termino de construir adecuadamente pues me retorna error

Comment: Hola, claro que lo puedes usar, seria asi vowels.contains(Character.toString(words.charAt(0))), en tu caso.

Comment: Muchísmas gracias por la ayuda